# Ruby on Rails 3 => truncate method with special characters throws Encoding Incompatability error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character, truncate

I need some help with the following. I got a string here which contains special characters e.g. ë, é etc. I can display them correctly in my view but once I call the **truncate** method, it throws the following error:

incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

The weird thing is that, when I inspect the encoding of the truncated string, it does give me UTF-8, which is what I need (and UTF-8 is used for my database).

my_string_with_special_characters.truncate(35).encoding.inspect 
=> UTF-8

But is is when I call:
<%= my_string_with_special_characters.truncate(35) %> 
=> incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

I have also tried the magic_encoding gem which prepends the magic comment 
"encoding : utf-8" in all of my controller files, but I still got the incompatible character encoding error.

If anyone knows how to solve this, let me know. Much appreciated.

Alex

Comment: What's the content of your string?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this string in the beginning of you file (for *.rb files)

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```